# How can I deserialize a YAML where not all keys have the same subkeys?

Tags: java, json, kotlin, yaml

Assume this YAML:

```yaml
base:
  foo:
    a: 'a'
    b: 'b'
    c: 'c'
  bar:
    a: 'a'
    b: 'b'
    c: 'c'
  baz:
    a: 'a'
    t: 't'
    z: 'z'
```

All the documentation I have found about deserializing a YAML imply that every key holds the same data.

So, for example, ignoring `baz`, I would use these data classes:

```kotlin
data class Base(val base: Data)
data class Data(val foo: Values, val bar: Values)
data class Values(val a: String, val b: String, val c :String)
```

My file actually has over 50 keys at the level of `foo,bar,baz`, and many of them don't share the same keys (not even the same number), so how could I define my data classes to be able to serialize it?

I tried the following:

```kotlin
data class Base(val base: Data)
data class Data(val d: List<Map<String, Values>>)
data class Values(val v: List<Map<String, String>>)
```

But it complains because it's looking for an exact match for the keys.

Comment: What are you using to parse that YAML?

Comment: @Fureeish [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Jackson object mapper with [support for yaml dataformat](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text) (`com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml`),
and the [Kotlin module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) (`com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin`).

The data class `Values` in your example does not match all objects, because for instance it does not contain `t` and `z` which are contained in the `base.baz` value.

One possibility is to broaden the definition of `Values` to contain all possible values there can be, ignoring any values that are not there:

```kotlin
data class Values(
    val a: String?,
    val b: String?,
    val c: String?,
    val t: String?,
    val z: String?,
)
```

All values are nullable to allow them to be absent.

If you do not need all the values, you could also add a `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation, to tell Jackson that it is not a problem if there are values in the yaml that are not declared in your data class:

```kotlin
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class Values(...
```

If this is not flexible enough, you can deserialize everything as a map:

```kotlin
val objectMapper = ObjectMapper(YAMLFactory()).registerKotlinModule()
val content: Map<String, *>  = objectMapper.readValue(theYaml)
```

Please note that in this case you gave Jackson no type information, and thus any non-trivial objects (i.e. not a `String`, `Int`, ...) in your yaml are deserialized as maps. Also, you don't have any type information yourself and you need to check every element if it is an instance of an expected type, and have to cast it manually.
For instance, to obtain element `base.foo.b` you can then write:

```
val base = content["base"]
val foo = (base as Map<String, *>)["foo"]
val b = (foo as Map<String, *>)["b"]
```

If `b` is of the non-trivial type, let's say `Something`, it can converted to the right type using

```
val bWithType: Something = objectMapper.convertValue(b)
```

But note that this means that `b` is again serialized and then deserialized to get it with the right type. So the better solution would be the approach with the more flexible `Values` class above. The alternative should only be used if it is necessary.

Comment: how can you access a given key later? because I can access only the top level. For example, I can access `content.get("base")` but I can't `content.get("base").get("foo")`

Comment: this is the error: `Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public inline operator fun <K, V> Map<out String, ???>.get(key: String): ??? defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun MatchGroupCollection.get(name: String): MatchGroup? defined in kotlin.text`

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad, I did not think of that. It is important to specify that you want to have a map with `String` keys. I modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the help, but it's still the same error. I'm using the Kotlin module and with neither `Map<*, *>` nor `Map<String, *>`, I can access any key beyond the top level.

Comment: @Ay0 I rewrote the answer again.

Comment: Finally managed to got it working with the last example. I had already tried `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` but it wasn't working either. And defining all the possible values in the data class was precisely what I didn't want to do and hence, why I opened this question :) thanks for the help